# find command with array versus string

Tags: shell

Why do this script work?

```
str=( -name "*.conf" -o -name "test test" )
find ./ \( "${str[@]}" \)
```

And this script not work?

```
str[0]="-name"
str[1]="\"*.conf\""
str[2]="-o"
str[3]="-name"
str[4]="\"test test\""
find ./ \( "${str[@]}" \)
```

It looks like error here: `str[1]="\"*.conf\""`

I'm interested in the second case.

Comment: To see how they differ, turn debugging on in your shell (`set -x`)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks... I'll use it. It's a very useful command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
str=( -name "*.conf" -o -name "test test" )
```

Is (usually) the same as this:

```
str=( "-name" "*.conf" "-o" "-name" "test test" )
```

Most of those quotes are omitted because they're not necessary - there are no wildcards for filename expansion, or whitespace characters from the default IFS that might cause field splitting for those elements.

So the equivalent could be:

```
declare -a str
str[0]="-name"
str[1]="*.conf"
str[2]="-o"
str[3]="-name"
str[4]="test test"
```

Or:

```
declare -a str
str[0]=-name
str[1]=*.conf    # no filename expansion in variable assignment
str[2]=-o
str[3]=-name
str[4]="test test"
```

Comment: `no filename expansion in variable assignment` - what do you mean?

Comment: @UnixUser in something like `ls *.conf`, `*.conf` undergoes filename expansion - it's expanded to a list of matching filenames. This doesn't happen during variable assignment.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand you. Can you write an example?

Comment: What part you having trouble understanding?

Comment: I need the 'find' search all files whose expansion looks like as `*.conf`. And you say if I'll use `str[1]=*.conf` then the `find` does not find them. Do I right understand you?

Comment: No, that's not what I said at all. I didn't say anything about find.

Comment: Any case thanks for the help. :)